# GWT DisclosurePanel slow down animation?

Tags: java, animation, gwt, widget

I "simply" wish to slow down the open/close animation on a DisclosurePanel.

Any ideas how to do this?

I see;

`private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 350;`

in the class. But the class cant be extended for some reason, so is there alternatives/workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it is impossible. I had some problems with DisclosurePanel as well (it is based on  and was not fitting well to my layout) and I just created my own collapsible panel. It turned out to be very easy. So if you want to have more controll over the animation or anything else I recommend you to write it by your self.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll take that path too.